# @RequestMapping at class level

Tags: spring-boot, controller

I'm new to springboot. I want to create a class with @RequestMapping at class level. I have a static html file located resource/static/main/index.html

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String Welcome(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String message(){
        return "main/index.html";
    }
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Hello Message!</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome everyone!

</body>
</html>
```

http://localhost:8080/home display Hello World in my browser. When I enter http://localhost:8080/home/message, I get a 404 message, The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. If I remove @RequestMapping("/home") from the class level then it works. My goal is to have mulitple @GetMapping and  @RequestMapping at the class level

Comment: Try `return "main/index"`

Comment: Try appending slash @RequestMapping("/home/")

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf to display your HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using thymeleaf then try:

```
@GetMapping("/message")
public String message(){
    return "main/index";
}
```

The index view location must be resources/templates

Comment: Thank you @Jar. I had to add the thymeleaf dependency then add the folder to the template directory. It is working now.